# Drop table from oracle database if table exist in sql statement

Tags: database, oracle, drop-table

I have to use an SQL statement to drop a table, it will crash if the table doesn't exist. Is it possible to use `IF` statement to drop the table
`s.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE employee");`

Comment: Are you doing this from a PLSQL block?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oracle does not support a construct like `drop table if exists my_table`, which is apparently legal syntax in MySQL (and possibly other RDBMSs).

In a `.SQL` script, where you're running `DDL` to `DROP` and/or `CREATE` various objects, the Oracle standard is to drop the object, and ignore the error in cases where the object does not exist.  If you wish, you can write code to check if the object exists (see `DBA_OBJECTS` view) to only drop if it exists.

from the `s.executeUpdate`, I gather that you're doing this in Java?  If it was me, I'd just do the drop and ignore any not exists error.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have the right permissions, you can do something like the below

```
declare var_count int;
select count(*) INTO var_count
from all_tables where OWNER = [schema] and table_name = "EMPLOYEE";
if var_count > 0 then
begin
drop table employee;
end
```

adapt accordingly if you are doing this in front-end code instead of a pl/sql procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This will resolve your problem, when the table doesn't exist no error will be thrown.

BEGIN
  DROP TABLE employee;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    NULL;
END;

Comment: You should really check if syntax is valid....

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally in pl/sql you can specify an exception section in the block, and catch the exception if the table is not there to drop.

See [Oracle errors handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208451/oracle-errors-handling?rq=1)

Answer (score -3):

I would use the following code:

```
s.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee")
```

But depending on your verions, you could also use this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.employee', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.employee
```

Answer taken from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887011/how-to-drop-table-if-exists-in-sql-server-2005), also this seems like it might be a duplicate of the same post?
I would highly, highly recommend reading the SQL Documentation, and trying to do a bit more research before posting, but sense I see you are new, be sure to read the rules of posting here on StackOverFlow.

Comment: Question is about Oracle, not SQL Server.

Comment: "...if table exist in sql statement" I just figured the question titled would reflect what the user wanted to learn?